# Finding property in nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
    var searchResults = new mongoose.Schema ({
        title : String,
        url : String,
        description : String,
        scrapped : {type : Boolean, default : false}
    });
```

And the other one :

```
var searchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    original : String,
    results : [searchResult],
    // ...
});
```

How should I go about searching a match for the URL value of a result?

I read in another question something that would be like:

```
var searchModel = mongoose.model('Search', searchSchema);
searchModel.findOne({'results.url' : "http://www.myurl.com"}, function (err, res) {
    consle.log(res);
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Presuming `searchModel` refers to a model based on schema `schem` i your code. That could be made more clear with an edit to your question.

Comment: Assuming `searchModel`'s schema is `schem`, that query syntax is correct.

Comment: You're right, my error happened to be somewhere else. I edited the question with more detailed code in case anyone finds it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is actually the correct one, my error was somewhere else.